# Change property of the nested element of the user control: WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I've got a user control - button with the vector image. I need to set a different vector image color (Fill="{Binding IconColor, FallbackValue='Black'}") on mouse over the button. Can't seem to figure out the right way to access it from the style.

I tried Fill="black" (without binding), still doesn't work. What am I missing, pls?

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlBarButton.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlBarButton"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >

<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Path x:Key="SettingsIcon" Data="M12,15.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 8.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,8.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 15.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,15.5M19.43,12.97C19.47,12.65 19.5,12.33 19.5,12C19.5,11.67 19.47,11.34 19.43,11L21.54,9.37C21.73,9.22 21.78,8.95 21.66,8.73L19.66,5.27C19.54,5.05 19.27,4.96 19.05,5.05L16.56,6.05C16.04,5.66 15.5,5.32 14.87,5.07L14.5,2.42C14.46,2.18 14.25,2 14,2H10C9.75,2 9.54,2.18 9.5,2.42L9.13,5.07C8.5,5.32 7.96,5.66 7.44,6.05L4.95,5.05C4.73,4.96 4.46,5.05 4.34,5.27L2.34,8.73C2.21,8.95 2.27,9.22 2.46,9.37L4.57,11C4.53,11.34 4.5,11.67 4.5,12C4.5,12.33 4.53,12.65 4.57,12.97L2.46,14.63C2.27,14.78 2.21,15.05 2.34,15.27L4.34,18.73C4.46,18.95 4.73,19.03 4.95,18.95L7.44,17.94C7.96,18.34 8.5,18.68 9.13,18.93L9.5,21.58C9.54,21.82 9.75,22 10,22H14C14.25,22 14.46,21.82 14.5,21.58L14.87,18.93C15.5,18.67 16.04,18.34 16.56,17.94L19.05,18.95C19.27,19.03 19.54,18.95 19.66,18.73L21.66,15.27C21.78,15.05 21.73,14.78 21.54,14.63L19.43,12.97Z" Fill="White" />

            <Style x:Key="i" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TheButton.ButtonImageRect.Fill" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="TheButton" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FFDDDDDD" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonStackPanel" Orientation="{Binding TheOrientation}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
            <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonImageRect" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="{Binding IconColor, FallbackValue='Black'}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}"/>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
            <Label x:Name="ButtonTextLabel" Content="{Binding TextLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}, FallbackValue='-button-'}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="6" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a Rectangle with an OpacityMask, I'd suggest to use a Path with a Stye that set the Fill property via a DataTrigger:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Geometry x:Key="SettingsIcon">M12,15.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 8.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,8.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 15.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,15.5M19.43,12.97C19.47,12.65 19.5,12.33 19.5,12C19.5,11.67 19.47,11.34 19.43,11L21.54,9.37C21.73,9.22 21.78,8.95 21.66,8.73L19.66,5.27C19.54,5.05 19.27,4.96 19.05,5.05L16.56,6.05C16.04,5.66 15.5,5.32 14.87,5.07L14.5,2.42C14.46,2.18 14.25,2 14,2H10C9.75,2 9.54,2.18 9.5,2.42L9.13,5.07C8.5,5.32 7.96,5.66 7.44,6.05L4.95,5.05C4.73,4.96 4.46,5.05 4.34,5.27L2.34,8.73C2.21,8.95 2.27,9.22 2.46,9.37L4.57,11C4.53,11.34 4.5,11.67 4.5,12C4.5,12.33 4.53,12.65 4.57,12.97L2.46,14.63C2.27,14.78 2.21,15.05 2.34,15.27L4.34,18.73C4.46,18.95 4.73,19.03 4.95,18.95L7.44,17.94C7.96,18.34 8.5,18.68 9.13,18.93L9.5,21.58C9.54,21.82 9.75,22 10,22H14C14.25,22 14.46,21.82 14.5,21.58L14.87,18.93C15.5,18.67 16.04,18.34 16.56,17.94L19.05,18.95C19.27,19.03 19.54,18.95 19.66,18.73L21.66,15.27C21.78,15.05 21.73,14.78 21.54,14.63L19.43,12.97Z</Geometry>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FFDDDDDD" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding TheOrientation}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
            <Path Data="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}"
                  Width="30" Height="30" Stretch="Uniform">
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding IconColor, FallbackValue=Black}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
            <Label Content="{Binding TextLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, FallbackValue='-button-'}"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="6" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```